# Best way to update jar for users?

Tags: java, jar

I have a game that is an executable jar file. The problem is, users need to manually download the newest version of the jar when there is an update.

As far as I know, I will need to make some sort of launcher that downloads the newest jar from my webserver and launches it. What is the best approach to doing this?

What I had in mind was creating another java application that downloads the game.jar to some behind the scenes directory and runs it.

Comment: [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html), which comes with all JREs, is designed to handle exactly this situation.  At a minimum, you must create a short XML file with a `.jnlp` extension, and place it on the web server, usually in the same directory as your .jar file.